# can nuget packages compiled against .net4.5 be referenced by dnxcore50

Tags: c#, nuget, dnx, .net-core

I'm compiling an application that targets the *dnxcore50* only.

I'm attempting  to reference a nuget package that I know works fine when run against dnx451. When I do `dnx . run` I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNXCore,Version=v5.0':

*it also suggests a `dnu restore` but the package is there*

It does not work for this package clearly so under what circumstances will it (if any) ?
In order for it to work must the package manager build a version compiled against dnxcore50?

### update

this chart makes things a bit clearer (copied from [here](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/))

[image]

Comment: "can nuget packages compiled against .net4.5 be referenced by dnxcore50" no.

Comment: @vcsjones is there a way to find out if the package in question is compiled against dnxcore50  or is there a list of packages that have been compiled (and thus can be referenced) ? The issue here is you can add the ref in project.json and the error message is not really all that clear: Even tho it does list the offending dll(s) there is no mention of what downstream is causing the issue. You can hazard a guess in some scenarios but a 'framework mismatch' error might be helpful vs a 'no really the assembly is missing' error

Comment: dnxcore50 is work in progress, it going to take a while before they can support all the framework assemblies on Linux/OSX targets.  Basic reason why dnx451 exists, it relies on the .NET Framework install on your machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `dnxcore50` indicates you're running on DNX on top of .NET Core. The only assemblies you can load in .NET Core are those that target a compatible profile, in this case e.g. `dnxcore50`, `dotnet`, or one of the compatible portable profiles.

If you have an assembly compiled against the full .NET Framework (via `net45`, `net451`, etc.), it won't run when on .NET Core as the same APIs aren't available.

Comment: at a glance (ie without downloading) is it possible to know whether a nuget package supports dnxcore50? (or framework x for that matter) eg https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/

Comment: No. The package has to be downloaded to see that information. You can use NuGet Package Explorer to quickly open a package directly from the feed to make it easier though.